# Macro button to switch to previous sheet

Tags: vba, excel

So I've been playing around with macros and buttons and I am trying to make a button, that on clicking it, it will go to the previous sheet (they are names Day 1, 2, 3, etc...) so I figure this shouldn't be too difficult!

Here is the code that I have got so far:

```
Sub Previous_Day()

    Worksheets("Day " & (sheetNum - 1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Worksheets("Day " & (sheetNum - 1)).Activate
    Worksheets("Day " & sheetNum).Visible = xlSheetHidden

    sheetNum = sheetNum - 1

End Sub
```

I get an error when I click the button with this which says "subscript out of range", I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, I globally define `sheetNum` in the 'This Workbook' module, and I shall show that code below:

```
Public sheetNum As Integer

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim start As Worksheet
Dim shName As String
Dim lastSheet As String



'name of the sheet template
shName = "Food Diary Template.xltm"
lastSheet = "Food Diary Last Entry.xltm"

Set start = Worksheets(1)
With start
    If .Range("A1") = "" Then
    .Range("A1") = Date
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 5").Select
    Selection.Delete
    .Range("B4").Select
    End If
End With

Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Activate
'#### I like to use variables for worksheets:
Set thisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

'Insert sheet template
With thisSheet
    If .Range("A1") < Date Then

        ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(436.5, 104.25, 58.5, 18.75).Select
        Selection.OnAction = "nextDay_Click"
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").Select
        Selection.Characters.Text = "Button 1"
        With Selection.Characters(start:=1, Length:=8).Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .FontStyle = "Regular"
            .Size = 11
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        End With
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").Select
        Selection.Characters.Text = "Next Day"
        With Selection.Characters(start:=1, Length:=8).Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .FontStyle = "Regular"
            .Size = 11
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        End With
        .Range("B4").Select

        Set sh = Sheets.Add(Type:="C:\Users\edawes\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\" & lastSheet, _
                            after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        '#### Put today's date in the new sheet:
        sh.Range("A1") = Date
        sh.Name = "Day " & Worksheets.Count
        'Worksheets(sh).Active
        sh.Range("B4").Select

       '#### Hide the old sheet
       .Visible = xlSheetHidden

    End If
End With

sheetNum = Sheets.Count

End Sub
```

This bit works fine as I want it to, but it's the `sheetNum` that I'm not sure about, have I done it right? I want it to be the total number of sheets when the file is opened and then when the button is pressed, (there is also a next day button, but that will be pretty simple when I get this one working), it will update the `sheetNum` variable so that it can keep track and the previous button can keep being pressed...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you use `sheetNum =ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count` in `Sub Previous_Day()`?

Comment: @Thinkingcap That doesn't appear to make a difference

Comment: Look at this : http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=536

Comment: To help us help you (and to help you help yourself), you should [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). All this other stuff about character formatting etc. just confuses the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just parse the *Name* of he active sheet, subtract one from the day number and activate the previous sheet.

```
Sub ButtonCode()
    dy = CLng(Split(ActiveSheet.Name, " ")(1))
    dy = dy - 1
    If dy = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Sheets("Day " & dy).Activate
End Sub
```

So if the name of the active sheet is **Day 4,** then sheet **Day 3** would be activated.